# Playing multiple video in sequence from sd card

Tags: android, video, view

Is it possible to load videos from sd card in grid view and get the uri of selected videos and play them in sequence using a single video view ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are asking to create a playlist sort of thing then yes you can do this by using a `onCompleteListener` of a video player. This event is fired when videoplayer finished player current item.

**Sample**

```
List<String> uris= new ArrayList<String>();
uris.add(uri1);
uris.add(uri2);

videoView.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {

        @Override
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            i = (i + 1) % uris.size();
            videoView.setVideoPath(uris.get(i));
        }
    });
```

P.S keep track of `i`

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer! Can you explain me the role of "i" ?  What exactly "i = (i+1)%uris.size()" does?

Comment: `i` is used to keep track of increaments happening. Lets say you have 5 uris in the list and 1 finished playing, then on onCompletion it first add 1 to the i and checks for remainder or in simple it checks for the bounds of an array

Comment: Okay so here is the problem! It works fine for the first five videos. When I select 6th video or videos after 5th index, it gets crash! Gives me error IndexOutOfBoundException.

Comment: Here is the code:-    Videoview.setVedioPath(Uris.get(i)); Videoview.start(); inside OnComplete listener i=(i+1)%uris.size(); Videoview.setVideoPath(Uris.get(i)); Videoview.start();

Comment: If you are manually selecting the 6th video to play then you need to modify the conditions in `onCompletion` thats your handling

Comment: What I am doing is.. First I will be selecting videos that I want to play. Then after onClick I will be playing those selected videos.

Comment: Yes, you need to handle those scenarios  and update the value of i. Above code assumes that you are starting from the first most

Comment: Oh yea! If I want to play third video, it gives me error. If I select first video, second video and then third video .. It works! Can you tell me where I went wrong?